# How to define a @Qualifier value from config file?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-cloud

Case:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("${value_from_config_file}")
A a;

config file:
value_from_config_file = a
```

just like:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("a")
A a;
```

However I failed with `@Qualifier("${value_from_config_file}")`.

How to implement this kind of requirement?
Or dynamic get a bean from config file indication.

Comment: That isn't supported and kind of would beat the purpose of `@Qualifier`. You have the full control of java at your fingertips, create an `@Bean` method that returns what you want based on the property or create configuration files and based on a property trigger the proper bean method.

Answer (score 0):

Define a configuration class like "AppConfig". Put "${value_from_config_file}" as "someValue" field in this class with a getter. Then write a public method which returns "someValue" as result. put @Bean on the top of the method with a given name. Then use this bean name as your @Qualifier